# why initialization in structure is done where object is created please see below code?

Tags: c, structure

why initialization in structure is done where object is created please see below code?

```
struct st {
    int i;
    char ch;
    float f;
};
int main() {
    struct st var = {2, 'h', 33.45}, var2; // here initialization is gud

    var2= {3, 't', 55}; // here initialization is bad why?

    printf("%d %c %f\n", var.i, var.ch, var.f);
    printf("%d %c %f\n", var2.i, var2.ch, var2.f);
}
```

Comment: `var2.i={3,'t',55};` how possible what it indicate from your point of view? look you accessing `int i` now not whole `struct`. it should be `var2`. what exactly you want? need to learn more about `c` for initialization and assignment.

Comment: I assume you mean `var2`, not `var2.i`, then it's a duplicate.

Comment: but you can write this `var2 = (struct st){3, 't', 55};` c99 later.

Answer (score 1):

After declaration, the below syntax can should be followed to init the structure elements.

```
    var2.i=2;
    var2.ch='t';
    var2.f=55;
```

This is the syntax of C language.

Comment: ok suppose ch[10] is declare in above structure    then why var2.ch="hello"; is not possible?

Comment: @rostrost, no var2.ch="hello"; is not possible if ch is array. suppose ch is char*ch then var2.ch="hello"; is possible.

Comment: thanks can u please explain why?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
struct st var2 = {3,'t',55};
```

or

```
struct st var2;
var2.i = 3;
var2.ch = 't';
var2.f = 55;
```

Comment: Wrong, if it were assignment, `var2 = {3,'t',55};` doesn't compile. See the duplicate question.

Comment: @YuHao please can u say why its not possible?

Comment: @rostrost See the duplicate question. 1. it's assignment, not initialization 2. C doesn't allow this syntax in assignment.

Comment: @YuHao s1.str="Hello";

is assignment. You can initialize a char array to a string literal, but not through assignment. can u please explain why its not possible with assignment?

Comment: @rostrost Because C doesn't allow it.

Comment: @YuHao ya i got it but there must be some technical reason?